# Why FragmentTransaction can't find the Layout area by it's ID? Showing error

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-fragments, android-linearlayout

I am practicing Fragment. The application has three buttons- *Start, Button 1, Button 2.* *Start* button should start the fragment, *Button 1* and *Button 2* shows the corresponding text.
The problem is in my MianActivity.java file. 
 line 34 shows an error:

[image]
My code:
MainActivity.java:

```
 package com.mycompany.fragment;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
//import android.support.v4.app.*;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
  @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
 android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
   android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
     StartFrag startFrag = new StartFrag();
  fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.textViewArea_1,startFrag);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
   }
public void clickButton(View view) {

         Fragment newFragment;
    if (view == findViewById(R.id.button)) {
        newFragment=new Fragment();
 } else if (view == findViewById(R.id.button1)) {
        newFragment= new Frag1();//shows error: "Incompitable types Required: android.support.v4.app.Fragment, Found: com.mycompany.fragment.Frag1"
    } else if (view == findViewById(R.id.button2)) {
        newFragment= new Frag2();//shows error: "Incompitable types Required: android.support.v4.app.Fragment Found: com.mycompany.fragment.Frag2"
    } else {
 newFragment=new Fragment();
    }
   android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction transaction=getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.textViewArea_1,newFragment);//Line 34
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        transaction.commit();
 }

}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="#468499">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Start"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:background="#6d0e0e"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:textColor="#147907"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:onClick="clickButton"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Fragment 1"
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="#6d0e0e"
        android:textColor="#147907"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:onClick="clickButton"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Fragment 2"
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:background="#6d0e0e"
        android:textColor="#147907"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:onClick="clickButton"/>


    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:id="@+id/textViewArea_1"
        android:background="#fbf896"></LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

StartFrag.java:

```
    package com.mycompany.fragment;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.*;

public class StartFrag extends Fragment{

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main,container,false);
    }
}
```

start_frag.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#468499">

</RelativeLayout>
```

Frag1.java:

```
    package com.mycompany.fragment;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class Frag1 extends Fragment {

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag_1,container,false);
    }
}
```

frag_1.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#468499">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:text="Fragment 1"
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textColor="#6d0e0e"
        android:textSize="40dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Frag2.java:

```
    package com.mycompany.fragment;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class Frag2 extends Fragment {

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag_2,container,false);
    }
}
```

frag_2.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#468499">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:text="Fragment 2"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textColor="#6d0e0e"
        android:textSize="40dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The error in Log:

[image]

Comment: So, this is a compiler error, not run-time issue.

Comment: Check your import, you are importing different class in different fragments. In one file you are importing import android.support.v4.app.Fragment; and in other you are importing import android.app.Fragment;
Make them same your code should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your StartFrag code file, add `import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;` . This is to ensure you are being consistent with `getSupportFragmentManager` method call. You have to remove `import android.Fragment`, assuming you have it.
The same compiler issue exists in other Java files. They need to `import android.support.v4.app.Fragment`.

Note: When you use the Studio Wizard, it inserts `import android.Fragment` to be compatible with Android 5 (Lollipop). But there is a compatibility issue with pre-Android 5 with Fragments. Hence you must do these **support.v4** imports, and change them manually.

Your current problem is just a compile error, my previous answer is still valid I think.

Comment: hi The Original Android, unfortunately nothing helps. Thst why this time i have posted my complete project. if u can please detect the error point. I know i may be very ignorant and insulted because of posting the whole project, but this was my only option.

Comment: Before I import your full project, I see one error. In MainActivity, FragmentTransaction is using android.support.v4.app, but it import android.app.FragmentTransaction; Change that to import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction (I do the same). Similarly, the file import android.app.Fragment, change that to android.support.v4.app.Fragment.  Basically there is a conflict here between the NEW Fragment (for Lollipop) and the pre-Lollipop android.support.v4.

Comment: It helps if you follow the path of the object declarations by pressing Control key and click on the object. In your case, click on Fragment. It should reference the package android.support.v4.app , in order to have the code consistent throughout. The Java compiler is forcing you to be consistent.

Comment: I am sorry! Look, I have done exactly the same thing as u said. but clickButton method still has error inside the loop. I have commented out the error (by updating my post).

Comment: Riyana, I can see there is progress here. You no longer have the compile error on line 34, related to transaction.replace(R.id.textViewArea_1,newFragment). However please learn from that code fix, for your sake. The code "newFragment= new Frag1()" also has the same compatibility problem. Look at Frag1.java, it has the "import android.app.Fragment", it needs to change to "import android.support.v4.app.Fragment" . If you control-click on Fragment in that file, it should reference to package android.support.v4.app, to be compatible. I'll update my answer for clarity.

Comment: Thank u very very much my sweet friend for being a part of my journey. It works after a long run. And off course i learn something important such as importing the appropriate stuff and compitability issue. and the answer is also accepted.

Comment: Wow, that's great news! I was hoping you did not quit. There is another post you did on "How do I make the ListView clickable...". There are a couple good answers, including mine. Review it again if you want, and I'll check. Another, if you think this answer is helpful, please click on the up-arrow too. I am trying to increase my rep by a lot this year.

Comment: i will take some steps to increase ur rep along the way.

Answer (score 1):

Everything looks fine to me except I do not know about your `StartFrag` class. It needs to be a subclass of `Fragment`. 
In `onCreateView`, you should inflate the xml for the fragment class like:
`inflater.inflate(R.layout.start_frag`...

Let us know.

Comment: thanks The Original Android, I have updated that class u asked for. And yes that class is also extended from Fragment. I have lot more to code though. but right now that is the only error I have I mentioned. I don't know what's wrong.

Comment: Return inflater.inflate(R.layout.start_frag,container,false); I have fixed this line according to ur suggestion. But the error never goes away. do i need to restart the android studio? I think i have something wrong with the layout ID (in activity_main.xml). It cant find the id, thou i did it correct way

Answer (score 0):

Please show your logcat . What error are you exactly facing?
One suggestion are you importing correct Fragment class?

As you are using android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager in that case the fragment class should be android.support.v4.app.Fragment instead of android.app.Fragment.
Please verify it and post your logact error.

Comment: Raj, i have updated the post with my complete code. does it help u to find the possible solution, since previous sugegstion didnt help me.